# Running Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

**Running Error**  Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'
So I'm continuously receiving a gradle build error upon trying to run my project. I have searched for other solutions and some say that adding:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
    // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
    // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
    // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
    exclude 'META-INF/notice'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}
```

But it doesn't work for me.The Error as below:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/rxjava.properties

```
**File1: E:\Workspace_Android\TravelStory\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\cn.bmob.android\bmob-sdk\3.5.0\jars\classes.jar
File2: C:\Users\Prometheus\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.reactivex\rxjava\1.2.1\4e4cfa4adc74521d5966799fa5ab70b733552f68\rxjava-1.2.1.jar**
```

I try to delete the File2 but after compile/gradle the file created again.
**studio version is 2.2.3

gradle version is 2.2.3**

My gradle file content as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.travelstory.travelstory"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true;
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
        // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
        // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
        // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //屏幕自动适配
    compile 'com.zhy:autolayout:1.4.5'
    //注解框架
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    //6.0权限rx
    compile 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.9.1@aar'
    //RxJava RxLifecycle生命周期管理
    compile 'com.trello:rxlifecycle:1.0'
    compile 'com.trello:rxlifecycle-components:1.0'
    //3.5.0：请务必查看下面注释[1]
    compile ('cn.bmob.android:bmob-sdk:3.5.0')
    //            {
    //        exclude group: 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    //    }
    //如果你想应用能够兼容Android6.0，请添加此依赖(org.apache.http.legacy.jar)
    compile 'cn.bmob.android:http-legacy:1.0'
    //bmob-push：Bmob的推送包
    compile 'cn.bmob.android:bmob-push:0.8'
    //多fragment多模块Activity
    compile 'me.yokeyword:fragmentation:0.9.3'
    // 如果想使用SwipeBack 滑动边缘退出Fragment/Activity功能，请再添加下面的库
    compile 'me.yokeyword:fragmentation-swipeback:0.7.9'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your not excluding the file the error is warning about.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/rxjava.properties

Here the complaint is `META-INF/rxjava.properties` so just update your `packageOptions` block to exclude this file explicitly.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    // ... and any other excludes go here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your gradle with this code:

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
```

This happens when there is a duplication of libraries